# Display the difference between two cells in excel status bar

Tags: vba, excel

I was looking for code to determine the difference between two selected cells and display it in the status bar of Excel 2010.

I found some code, but it applies only to the workbook that contains that code.
Is it possible to make this code functional on every workbook I am working with?
It would be great if this kind of code runs automatically like macros from personal.xlsb.

```
Public Sub workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Set sh = ActiveSheet
If Selection.Cells.Count = 2 Then
   On Error Resume Next
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Selection.Address)) = 2 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "The difference is " & _
        WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Selection.Address)) _
        - WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Selection.Address))
    Else
        Application.StatusBar = "The difference is " & _
        WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Selection.Address))
    End If
Else
    Application.StatusBar = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this work with Excel 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found some code, but it applies only to the workbook that contains that code. Is it possible to make this code functional on every workbook I am working with?

You will have to create an Add-In for this. And then place this in your Add-In's `ThisWorkbook` module. After the Add-In has been created, activate it by checking its check-box on the Developer Tab, Add-Ins Section.

```
Private WithEvents oXLApp As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set oXLApp = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub oXLApp_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
ByVal Target As Range)
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code here
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: So we right click and add the above code to the window that displays? Where do we place the code the @afmoroz had in his question?

Answer (score 0):

These question resulted in the following tool.

Save the following project as .xla

Thisworkbook:

```
Private WithEvents oXLApp As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set oXLApp = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub oXLApp_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As range)

Dim limit As Long
limit = 300000 ' selection limit

Dim frmt As String
frmt = "#,##0;(#,##0);""-""" ' formating at status bar

' first condition - one selection area


If Selection.Areas.Count = 1 Then

On Error Resume Next
If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 And Selection.Cells.Count < limit Then
   On Error Resume Next
        Application.StatusBar = _
            "       D:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(Selection) - WorksheetFunction.Min(Selection), frmt) & _
            "       U:    " & Format(Unique(Selection), frmt) & _
            "       2X:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection) * 2, frmt) & _
            "       X2:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Selection) / 2, frmt) & _
            "       NC:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, "<0"), frmt) & _
            "       NS:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Selection, "<0"), frmt)
Else


If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Or Selection.Cells.Count >= limit Then
   On Error Resume Next
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If ' No condition
End If ' Cells > 2 and < limit
End If ' Areas = 1 - end of first condition


' second condition - more than one selection areas



If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Then

Dim r1 As range
Dim r2 As range
Set r1 = Selection.Areas(1)
'WorksheetFunction.Sum (r1)
On Error Resume Next
Set r2 = Selection.Areas(2)
'Set multipleRange = Union(r1, r2)

On Error Resume Next
If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 And Selection.Cells.Count < limit Then
   On Error Resume Next
        Application.StatusBar = _
            "       D:    " & Format(DIFF(r1, r2), frmt) & _
            "       U:    " & Format(Unique(r1), frmt) & _
            "       2X:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(r1) * 2, frmt) & _
            "       X2:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.Sum(r1) / 2, frmt) & _
            "       NC:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r1, "<0"), frmt) & _
            "       NS:    " & Format(WorksheetFunction.SumIf(r1, "<0"), frmt)
Else


If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Or Selection.Cells.Count >= limit Then
   On Error Resume Next
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End If ' no condition
End If ' Cells > 1
End If ' Areas > 1 - end of second condition

End Sub
```

Module 1:

```
Public Function DIFF(rng1 As range, rng2 As range)
   DIFF = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng1) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng2)
End Function
```

Module 2:

```
Public Function Unique(ByRef rngToCheck As range) As Variant

    Dim colDistinct As Collection
    Dim varValues As Variant, varValue As Variant
    Dim lngCount As Long, lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    varValues = rngToCheck.Value

    'if rngToCheck is more than 1 cell then
   'varValues will be a 2 dimensional array
   If IsArray(varValues) Then

        Set colDistinct = New Collection

        For lngRow = LBound(varValues, 1) To UBound(varValues, 1)
            For lngCol = LBound(varValues, 2) To UBound(varValues, 2)

                varValue = varValues(lngRow, lngCol)

                'ignore blank cells and throw error
               'if cell contains an error value
               If LenB(varValue) > 0 Then

                    'if the item already exists then an error will
                   'be thrown which we want to ignore
                   On Error Resume Next
                    colDistinct.Add vbNullString, CStr(varValue)
                    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

                End If

            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow

        lngCount = colDistinct.Count
    Else
        If LenB(varValues) > 0 Then
            lngCount = 1
        End If

    End If

    Unique = lngCount

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Unique = CVErr(xlErrValue)

End Function
```

Comment: Does someone know how to make all these things work correctly on filtered ranges?
Excel’s Sum, Average, Count… functions in the status bar consider only visible cells.
Also to mention is that native status bar functions work very fast, whereas the VBA from above can’t handle many rows.

Comment: I experimented with xlcelltypevisible but it was very slow.